# Calculate the difference between rows

Tags: r

I have a matrix that kind of looks like this

```
 M = matrix( 1:12, ncol=1)
```

I now would like to fetch the difference between the rows. So the value of row 2 - row 1.

I could write a loop that subtracts the element of that row and the element of the row -1 but something tells me there's a more efficient way.

Any thoughts on how I can do this better?

Comment: How about `diff` function?

Comment: Thanks @Pascal exactly what I was looking for