# Bring data previous day using r

Tags: sql, r

```
Date        Profit        
2018-01-18  3024490

2018-01-17  3985331

2018-01-16  5987905 

2018-01-15  5742019 

2018-01-14  4645206

2018-01-13  4766255
```

I have data table like above, want to know profit difference and growth rate between days ultimately.

So I think I had to make a new column called `previous day profit`, bring previous day's data into new column and `aggregate` between two columns. I mean two days data should be in the same row for example) 2018-1-1 profit / 2018-1-2 profit should be in the same row to compare the prices between 2 days.

Please help me!

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! This question has been asked a few times before (if I understand you correctly) so I'm just going to link you to another anwser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651295/calculate-the-difference-between-rows)

Answer (score 2):

A fully worked example using dplyr showing the steps.

```
library(dplyr)
data = read.table(header = T, 
                  text="Date Profit        
                  2018-01-18  3024490
                  2018-01-17  3985331
                  2018-01-16  5987905 
                  2018-01-15  5742019 
                  2018-01-14  4645206
                  2018-01-13  4766255")

data = 
  data %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  mutate(PreviousProfit = lag(Profit)) %>% 
  mutate(Difference = Profit - PreviousProfit)

data
#        Date  Profit PreviousProfit Difference
#1 2018-01-13 4766255             NA         NA
#2 2018-01-14 4645206        4766255    -121049
#3 2018-01-15 5742019        4645206    1096813
#4 2018-01-16 5987905        5742019     245886
#5 2018-01-17 3985331        5987905   -2002574
#6 2018-01-18 3024490        3985331    -960841
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `lag()` function in the `dplyr` package is ideal for.

Let's first create your dataframe, `df`, using `tribble` from the `tibble` package.

```
library(tibble)
df <- tribble(
       ~Date,  ~Profit,        
"2018-01-18",  3024490,
"2018-01-17",  3985331,
"2018-01-16",  5987905,
"2018-01-15",  5742019,
"2018-01-14",  4645206,
"2018-01-13",  4766255)
```

Now we can load `dplyr` and get to work. Basically, the thing you have to do is create a new column using `mutate` and make that column a lag of Profit. But before we do that we arrange the dataframe according to the `Date` column, so that the lag is actually referring to the previous day when it refers to the previous row.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  mutate(prev_day_profit = lag(Profit))
```

Which results in the following when we print the data.frame `df`.

```
> df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
        Date  Profit prev_day_profit
       <chr>   <dbl>           <dbl>
1 2018-01-13 4766255              NA
2 2018-01-14 4645206         4766255
3 2018-01-15 5742019         4645206
4 2018-01-16 5987905         5742019
5 2018-01-17 3985331         5987905
6 2018-01-18 3024490         3985331
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Very happy to help :)